# Strange Log4J error calling grails war w/ Grails 2.1

Tags: grails, logging, log4j

When I am executing `grails -skipTests -verbose -plainOutput war` on the command line it tries to configure logging for production environment. However, I do not want any app logging while building the war. Does anybody know why Grails tries to do that and how to avert it? Thanks.

The directory where it tries to log to does not exist on the BuildAgent. But this is the point. There is no app running, I just want to build a war.

My log config:

```
// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    appenders {
        def logDir = '/someDirectory/'

        if (Environment.getCurrentEnvironment() in [Environment.DEVELOPMENT, Environment.TEST]) {
            logDir = 'log/'
        }

        def logFile = "${logDir}someLog.log"
        def stacktraceLogFile = "${logDir}stacktrace.log"

        appender new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(name: "file",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{[ dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss.SSS]} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"),
                file: logFile,
                datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd")

        appender new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(name: "stacktrace",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{[ dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss.SSS]} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"),
                file: stacktraceLogFile,
                datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd")
    }

    error 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
            'org.springframework'

    root {
        warn 'stdout', 'file'

        environments {
            production {
                error 'stdout', 'file'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My stacktrace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /someDirectory/stacktrace.log (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:192)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
...
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:226)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:748)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:551)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:452)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:396)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:371)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:232)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
```

***Update***

I just noticed that this exception is exposed only when verbose logging is enabled with Grails (i.e. on my Jenkins build agent). To me it seems like an undesirable behavior that is hidden by normal stdout logging.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably means that `/someDirectory` doesn't exist and log4j doesn't have the necessary permissions to create it.

From the stack trace, it seems that Grails does initialize the config, probably because most commands need it.

My suggestion is to create another environment in the Grails main config file which either doesn't configure log4j at all or which configures only the console appender.

Alternatively, move the file appender to the production config or configure it to write to a relative path in the development config and override this path in production.

**[EDIT]** Replace

```
def logDir = '/someDirectory/'
```

with

```
def logDir = System.getProperty( 'appname.logDir', '/someDirectory/' );
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it seems I could not express myself clear enough. I do not even startup a Tomcat. I am just building a war. Even though log4j tries to write that log file and I do not understand why

Comment: Sorry and thanks for pushing my head there again :-)

But this is exactly what I want to know. IF those commands need it and why it is that way. Because when I know, I know what to do.

I'll dig into your alternative suggestion later.

Comment: I think you truncated the interesting part out of the stack trace

Comment: Yes I did. I just looked into it and the createWar target simply initializes the log4j config. That is why a different environment will not work: I want to create a war for production environment, so of course I need to use the same configuration.

The question for me now is, how I can disable a prod environment appender for grails prod war.

Comment: You could look up the logDir from a System property :-/ See my edits.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15173/discussion-between-pvblivs-and-aaron-digulla)